# How to compare values of specific index in an array in open cart

Tags: php, sql, arrays, opencart

i have an array $ results, which gives me following output when i do print_r on it.

```
Array ( 
    [0] => Array ( 
        [parent_geo_zone_id] => 3 
        [name] => UK VAT Zone 
        [shipping_pool_geo_zone_id] => 
        [email] => 
    ) 
    [1] => Array ( 
        [parent_geo_zone_id] => 4 
        [name] => UK Shipping 
        [shipping_pool_geo_zone_id] => 
        [email] => 
    ) 
    [2] => Array ( 
        [parent_geo_zone_id] => 5 
        [name] => Texas 
        [shipping_pool_geo_zone_id] => 5 
        [email] => ammar.instantsoft@gmail.com 
    ) 
    [3] => Array ( 
        [parent_geo_zone_id] => 6 
        [name] => florida 
        [shipping_pool_geo_zone_id] => 6 
        [email] => ammar_ul_hasan@hotmail.com 
    ) 
    [4] => Array ( 
        [parent_geo_zone_id] => 7 
        [name] => alaska 
        [shipping_pool_geo_zone_id] => 
        [email] => 
    ) 
)
```

I want to compare the following indexes

```
'parent_geo_zone_id' and 'shipping_pool_geo_zone_id '
```

like this

```
if($results->array['parent_geo_zone_id']==$results->array['shipping_pool_geo_zone_id '])
```

where ever these two ids are equal i want to send my checkbox value as checked to view other wise unchecked like this.

```
 foreach ($results as $result) {

            $this->data['geo_zones'][] = array(
                'geo_zone_id' => $result['parent_geo_zone_id'],
                'name'        => $result['name'],
                'email'       => $result['email'],

                'selected'    => isset($this->request->post['selected']) && in_array($result['geo_zone_id'], $this->request->post['selected'])

            );
```

I am using open cart.

Comment: `if($result['parent_geo_zone_id'] === $result['shipping_pool_geo_zone_id '])`

Comment: @splash58 it saying Notice: Undefined index: shipping_pool_geo_zone_id

Comment: `if($result['parent_geo_zone_id'] === $result['shipping_pool_geo_zone_id']);` I forget space when take yor code :) test now

Comment: @splash58 now there is no error but it is always getting false in if condition.. ?? how can i send checkbox as  as uncheck in else case and checked in if case?

Comment: `if($result['parent_geo_zone_id'] === $result['shipping_pool_geo_zone_id']) echo 'Yes';` do you see 'Yes' ?

Comment: yes i do see yes when these two are equal in my case the output is "nonoYesYesno" in else i have echoed no. so its perfect. now i want to send checkbox checked to my view in IF case and in else i want unchecked..

Comment: @splash58 thanks i have done it if u post your above condition in answer i will approve it ;)

Comment: I done. You are welcome

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You just can use such expression

```
if($result['parent_geo_zone_id'] === $result['shipping_pool_geo_zone_id'])
  {
  // any stuff for true
  } 
else
  {
  // any stuff for false
  }
```